# hook after every Scenario Outline?

Tags: python, pytest, hook, gherkin

I need to do something after every outline scenario.
I saw an answer for Java - But couldn't implement it with Python.
Can this be done in Python pytest?

```
    @test1
      Scenario Outline: test1
        Given go "<place>"
        Examples:
          | place |
          | here  |
          | there |
    @test2
      Scenario Outline: test2
        Given go "<place>"
        Examples:
          | place |
          | far   |
          | close
```

In the example above - how do I call a function between test1 and test2?